# Windows RAM disk that can be installed on the command line, and supports > 4GB?

Tags: windows, command-line, ramdisk

Is there a Windows RAM disk that can:

- Be installed/controlled from the command line.
- Supports > 4GB on a 64-bit system.

I've written a .NET app to decompress some .rar files to a temporary directory, do some operations, then delete the decompressed files. Due to various technical reasons (mainly to do with speed), I'm calling the command line version of .rar behind the scenes. Setting up a RAM disk in effect gives Windows a hint: "when you decompress these files to a directory, you don't have to persist them to disk" which will definitely speed things up in the long run.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you want a RAM disk? Chances are that if you're hitting a set of files regularly, that you're going to be reading them from cache anyhow.

Comment: I've written a .NET app to decompress some .rar files to a temporary directory, do some operations, then delete the decompressed files. Due to various technical reasons (mainly to do with speed), I'm calling the command line version of .rar behind the scenes. Setting up a RAM disk in effect gives Windows a hint: "when you decompress these files to a directory, you don't have to persist them to disk" which will definitely speed things up in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there doesn't seem to be one that supports files bigger than 4 GB.

In the end, I've decided to implement memory-based decompression of `.rar` files in my .NET app.